# C# Entity Framework - returning list of single entity after a join lambda query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two classes:

```
public class classA
{
    public string keyA {get; set;}
    public string propAA {get; set;}    
    public string propAB {get; set;}
    public string propAC {get; set;}        
}

public class classB
{
    public string keyB {get; set;}
    public string foreignkeyA {get; set;}
    public string propBA {get; set;}    
    public string propBB {get; set;}
    public string propBC {get; set;}        
}
```

If I do a join between them..

```
var query = db.ClasseA.
            Join(db.ClasseB, a => a.keyA, b => b.foreignkeyA,
                (ca, cb) => new { ca, cb })
                .Where(q => q.cb.propBC == 'some value')
                .Select();
```

The result is a combination (list) of **classA** and **classB** objects.

But, I need that the result is only a list of **class A**.

Something like:

```
List<classA> query = db.ClasseA.
            Join(db.ClasseB, a => a.keyA, b => b.foreignkeyA,
                (ca, cb) => new { ca, cb })
                .Where(q => q.cb.propBC == 'some value')
                .Select(????);
```

How can I do that??

Comment: really you get that far and you are stuck at the select. But all that is  needed in the select should be x=> x.ca

Answer (score 0):

One example

```
var query = from obj1 in db.Object1
            join obj2 in db.Object2 on obj1.key equals obj2.somekey
            where obj1.something = "something"
            select obj1
```

This will join the two but only bring back obj1 items

reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx